# How to view comments of a function in bash

Tags: bash, shell, alias

To read a function definition, you can use one of the below

```
typeset -f <func_name>    # OR
declare -f <func_name>    # OR 
type <func_name>
```

But none of the above commands shows the comments defined inside the function. Is there a command/option which shows comments too along with the definition.

Comment: Comments are ignored when parsing the function deifnition, they're not saved anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The comments are treated as comments when the function is defined, and are not part of the function itself.  But there is a workaround.
You can pass arguments to `:` as a form of comment.  eg:

```
$ foo() { echo foo; : this is a comment; }
$ typeset -f foo
foo () 
{ 
    echo foo;
    : this is a comment
}
```

Comment: Thanks William. If you try to use any bash specific char (e.g open and close brackets) it will throw relevant error. To avoid it I had used quotes around the comment

Answer (score 2):

Also you could use heredoc. @William answers works for multi line comments as well if surrounded with quotes.

```
foo() {
    <<'##'
       This is a comment
       more comments
##
echo foo
}

foo() {
    : '
       This is a comment
       more comments
'
echo foo
}
```